# Parsing a directory of logs in Hadoop 0.20.2

Tags: java, hadoop

I have a directory of text-based, compressed log files, each containing many records. In older versions of Hadoop I would extend `MultiFileInputFormat` to return a custom `RecordReader` which decompressed the log files and continue from there. But I'm trying to use Hadoop 0.20.2.

In the Hadoop 0.20.2 documentation, I notice `MultiFileInputFormat` is deprecated in favor of `CombineFileInputFormat`. But to extend `CombineFileInputFormat`, I have to use the deprecated classes `JobConf` and `InputSplit`. What is the modern equivalent of `MultiFileInputFormat`, or the modern way of getting records from a directory of files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the modern equivalent of MultiFileInputFormat, or the modern way of getting records from a directory of files?

o.a.h.mapred.* has the old API, while the o.a.h.mapreduce.* is the new API. Some of the Input/Output formats have not been migrated to the new API. MultiFileInputFormat/CombineFileInputFormat have not been migrated to the new API in 20.2. I remember a JIRA being opened to migrate the missing formats, but I don't remember the Jira #.

> But to extend CombineFileInputFormat, I have to use the deprecated classes JobConf and InputSplit.

For now it should be OK to use the old API. Check this [response](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hadoop-common-user/201203.mbox/%3CCAOcnVr0osRAwytaU7LT+agf0BmMCWFhRGpj8_Ga4U6MaC2YkpA@mail.gmail.com%3E) in the Apache forums. I am not sure of the exact plans for stopping the support to the old API. I don't think many have started using the new API, so I think it would be supported for a foreseeable future.